# How to create dask series from dask array (dd.from_dask_array)

Tags: dask

I´m having trouble to create a dask series from a dask array:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd

_dict = {'doc_faturamento': ['546102424238','946102424238','777702424238'],'data_vencimento':[20190307,20190310,20190311], 'data_pagamento': [20190227,20190324,22220202],'periodo_atraso': [-8,14, 74107], 'periodo_atraso': ['PA/PD', '8-14 días', 'INAD']}

_df = pd.DataFrame( data=_dict)

_df = dd.from_pandas(_df, npartitions=2)

_peri = da.where(_df['data_pagamento']=='2222-02-02','INAD',_df['periodo_atraso'])
_peri_df = dd.from_dask_array(_peri)
_df['periodo_atraso'] = _peri
```

Even do with this example, I´m getting the right result:

```
_test = da.from_array(np.arange(100000, 190000), chunks=1000)
_test_df = dd.from_dask_array(_test)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `da.where` on a dask dataframe.  I recommend looking at `dd.DataFrame.where` or `dd.Series.where` instead